# Does multiprocessing work like this normally?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

> Source Code

```
import multiprocessing
import time


inTime = time.time()
def sleeper():
    print("Im sleeper")
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(sleeper())
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(sleeper())
    p2.start()
    p2.join()

    nTime = time.time()
    print(f"done in {round(nTime-inTime,2)} s")
```

I'm not getting it to work as expected.
It must complete the process within 1s but it takes 2s queuing one function after another.
I'm running it on Python 3.11.1 [64bit]

Comment: You're starting the process and waiting for it to finish before starting the next.

Comment: [Here is an example of what using `join()` does.](https://zetcode.com/python/multiprocessing/#:~:text=AdvertisementsPython%20multiprocessing%20join,until%20the%20process%20gets%20terminated.&text=The%20example%20calls%20the%20join%20on%20the%20newly%20created%20process.)

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I see it. But after sleep fn() is called, the wait time is 3s `joining.py` (on this same page) which should be just 1s.

Comment: You are calling `sleeper()` and then trying to use its result as the target for the multiprocessing call. So, no multiprocessing. In addition to the join issue, you should do `p1 = multiprocessing.Process(sleeper)` - that is, hand in the function to be called in the subprocess. I don't know why `multiprocessing` doesn't error when its target is not callable.

Comment: I think that if you move `p1.join()` next to `p2.join()` the runtime should be about 1s.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Makes not difference.

Comment: Did you leave out the call to the function and instead passed it as a paramater like @tdelaney mentioned?

Comment: I tried this and it works `multiprocessing.Process(target=sleeper)`
Time: 1.19s

Comment: As a note on question writing, you should (1) run the code you post - this example has a bug in it, and (2) include the output you get. Otherwise this is a great example script and we can spot the problem quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems. First, you call `sleeper()` and then create a process that does nothing. Second, you join the first process before even starting the second. Third, the target subprocess function should be in the `target` parameter. To get things to go in parallel, you can do

```
import multiprocessing
import time

inTime = time.time()
def sleeper():
    print("Im sleeper")
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleeper)
    p1.start()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleeper)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    nTime = time.time()
    print(f"done in {round(nTime-inTime,2)} s")
```

Output

```
Im sleeper
Im sleeper
done in 1.01 s
```